# Div html code not extracting from html code

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**java script code**

```
 $("#category select").change(function(){
 var category = $('select option:selected').html();

 $.ajax({
    type:"Post",
    url:"collectiepost.php",
    data:"category="+category,
    cache:"false",
    success:function(html){

 $("select").html($(html).find("option.category"));
 $("#test").html($(html).find("#testdata"));
    }
    });
  });
 });
```

html output on that page collectiepost.php

```
 <select id="ontwerper">
 <option class="desinger">vikas</option>
 </select>

 <select id="category">
 <option class="category">cloth1</option>
 <option class="category">cloth2</option>
 </select>

 <div id="testdata">test data</div>
```

**need output**

```
<select>
<option class="category">cloth1</option>
<option class="category">cloth2</option>
</select>

 <div id="test">
 <div id="testdata">test data</div>   
 </div>
```

**problem**

but my getting those output without div tag

```
<select>
<option class="category">cloth1</option>
<option class="category">cloth2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in "`div #test`" in the following line:

```
$("div #test").html($(html).find("div #testdata"));
```

Comment: i have done like that also $("#test").html($(html).find("#testdata")); but not working

Comment: What I meant was, change this line to `$("div#test").html($(html).find("div#testdata"));` You have a space between `div` and `#test` in both places. What's happening is that ajax call looks for an element with id="test" inside the all the div elements instead of looking for a div element with id="test"

Comment: On the page where you want the response `#testdata` part inserted, do you already have an element with `id="test"` or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get this:

```
<div id="test">
 <div id="testdata">test data</div>   
</div>
```

is because in your html output you do not have the "test" div:

```
<select id="ontwerper">
 <option class="desinger">vikas</option>
 </select>

 <select id="category">
 <option class="category">cloth1</option>
 <option class="category">cloth2</option>
 </select>

 <div id="testdata">test data</div>
No test div here
```

and `$("div #test").html($(html).find("div #testdata"));` fails

Wrap it like this:

```
$('#testdata').wrap('<div id="test" />');
```

Comment: i m want get this line <div id="testdata">test data</div> inside the <div id="test"></div>

Comment: @vikastyagi the wrap do exactly that